# Wordpress listen to the event "update" or "move to the trash" the post

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to know if there is a function in php, or an event that we can subscribe to that is called each time an admin click on "update" a post or "move it to the trash" ? By the way, is it also possible to display a pop up on the admin page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress uses Hooks, which is basically saying I want to hook my function on yours, so when you get called, my function gets called. You have Action Hooks and Filter Hooks.

You can look all action hooks up here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

You can look all filter hooks up here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference

the one you're looking for is probably this one: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post - the moment you save a post
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post - Just before the post is deleted (after deleted post is also shown on this one)

you can use it like this:

```
<?php
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_function' );

my_function($post_id) {
    //do stuff here
}
?>
```

Do note that this is only for when you create plugins, I'm not sure what you're doing, but this only works when creating plugins.

if you prefer object oriented plugins, you can call functions with this:

```
<?php
add_action( 'save_post', array($this, 'my_function') );
?>
```

remember that you need to have my_function() inside the class!

Hope this helps.

Comment: do you know if it's possible to display a pop up on the admin page when the user click on 'update the post' ?

Comment: Once you hooked a function to the action, you can do everything in php's power to the site. You can for example echo a javascript script, then open a new window linked to a file. This is up to you (if you want a div popup, you will need some more work, but you'll have to google that :P).